# Как отправить ответ на сервер до выполнения скрипта?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Подскажите, как отправить ответ на сервер сразу после получения запроса, а после уже обработать его и ответить еще раз? Не используя Celery и RQ..

Comment: в чём специфичность вашей задачи, что celery, rq не подходят?

Comment: Нужно решить задачу без них. С ними я это уже сделал, но нужно прям без них

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранять данные для выполнения задачи в БД. Возвращать пользователю id задачи (чтобы по нему потом получить результат).

А дальше эту задачу выполняйте хоть отдельным процессом, хоть по crontab (если не используете rq или Celery), пишите результат в БД, и по запросу отдавайте готовые данные пользователю.